# Nested maps in react return an empty page

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm attempting to iterate over a series of dates, and then render objects which match.

### Dates aren't being stored

The dates need to be stored in a state `datesarray[]` (although only the keys are), and the events are similarly stored in an arrant of `events[]`. And both are populated as below:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5002/events')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            {/* Orders descending */}
            this.setState({events: data.sort(
                (event1,event2) => -event1.date.localeCompare(event2.date))})
    
                {/* Places dates into an array */}
                let eventdate = "";
                for (var r in data) {
                    eventdate = r.date;
                    console.log("help");
    
                    if (!this.state.datesarray.includes(eventdate)) {
                        this.state.datesarray.push(eventdate);
                    }
                }
          }
    ).catch(console.log)
}
```

I modified the for loop to use Object.keys, however this similarly provides a key, not a date value:

```js
{/* Places dates into an array */}
{Object.keys(data).map(date => this.setState({ datesarray: [...this.state.datesarray, date] }))}
```

Below produced by

```js
// convert object to key's array
Object.keys(data).forEach(val => console.log(val));
Object.values(data).forEach(val => console.log(val));
```

[image]

### Partial success #1

On running the app without mapping the next date I do get results.

```js
render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
        {this.state.events
            .filter(event => event.date
            .includes({date}))
            .map(filteredEvent =>(
                <Events event={filteredEvent} />
                
            )
         )
     }
 )}
 </div>      
}
```

However, nothing is rendered when attempting this with an outer map to get the date stored in the `datesarray[]`

```js
render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
        {this.state.datesarray.map(date =>
            {this.state.events
            .filter(event => event.date
            .includes({date}))
            .map(filteredEvent =>(
                <Events event={filteredEvent} />
            ))}
        )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

### Partial Success #2

I can now store dates in mt `componentDidMount` with:

```js
Object.values(data).forEach(val =>{
    !datesarray.includes(val.date) && datesarray.push(val.date)
});
```

And I can print *separately* the dates and the records. Remember I'm attempting to group here with nested maps. I just can't figure out how to print them together.

I'm attempting to get the `{date}` value in the first map, into the `.includes` value.

```js
render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            {this.state.datesarray.map(date => <h1>{date}</h1>)}
            {this.state.events
             .filter(event => event.date
             .includes("2020-09-30"))
             .map(filteredEvent =>(
                 <Events event={filteredEvent} />
             )
      )}
      </div>
      );
    
}
```

Comment: I've just realised the problem lies with the dates not being populated into the array. Let's see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I've figured out how to add items to the array. However, I'm adding the keys not the date values I wanted. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the issue with correctly placing the dates into the array done like so:

```
  const events = [...data].sort((event1, event2) => (-event1.date.localeCompare(event2.date)));
  let datesarray = [...this.state.datesarray];

  // convert object to key's array
  //  Object.keys(data).forEach(val => console.log(val));
  Object.values(data).forEach(val =>{
    !datesarray.includes(val.date) && datesarray.push(val.date)

  });
```

I also managed to nest the two mappings. One of the frustrations was the `.includes({date})` should have been `.includes(date)`

```
render() {


return(


  <div className="container">


  {this.state.datesarray.map(date => {


    return(

      <div>
      <h6>{date}</h6>

            {this.state.events
              .filter(event => event.date
                .includes(date))
                .map(filteredEvent =>(
                  <Events event={filteredEvent} />

                )
              )
            }
      </div>
    )

  })}



  </div>

);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating state when you push each `eventdate` to `this.state.datesarray`. The React render cycle is based on snapshots of immutable state, and rerenders are only triggered when `setState` is called. It's usually a good idea to completely separate data processing and state setting into discrete operations to avoid mutations like this.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5002/events')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {

    const events = [...data].sort((event1, event2) => (
      -event1.date.localeCompare(event2.date)
    ));
    let datesarray = [...this.state.datesarray];
    
    for (let r in data) {
      !datesarray.includes(r.date) && datesarray.push(r.date);
    };
    
    this.setState({
      events,
      datesarray
    });

  }).catch(console.log);
};
```

Comment: I'm just getting my head round to understand this (thank you) however, I'm getting an error `TypeError: event1.date.localCompare is not a function. (In 'event1.date.localCompare(event2.date)', 'event1.date.localCompare' is undefined)`

Comment: Typo, it should be `localeCompare`, I always get that one wrong.

Comment: Ok that works sort of. I'm now rendering one line but without the data. I think this might be because `data` is an array of objects. Each of which contains a value `date`. Should I be using `r.date` as above? Or should I reference the object somehow?

Comment: Can't really advise much further as I'm not sure what the render is supposed to look like. I wonder if it should just be `.includes(date)` before `.map(filteredEvent => ...)`.

Comment: Nope, and doing an Object.keys and Object.values in your example provides the output on the screenshot I just added. I'm writing object keys to the `datesarray` not individual values within the objects.